What is magnetic shear?
Can someone please summarise to me what exactly magnetic shear is? I know shear as $\tau=F/A$, and intuitively interpret is as, eg, a force on an object and the friction response being shear forces. What would the equivalent be for magnetic shear?

As Dale points out shear is of course more general than the version you know. If you ever learn about solid/fluid/continuum mechanics they delve into the more general notion of shear of which that formula is a result in simplified situations.

In electromagnetism there is the Maxwell stress tensor which is given by: $$\sigma_{ij}=\epsilon_0 \left( E_i E_j - \frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij} E^2 \right) + \frac{1}{\mu_0} \left( B_i B_j - \frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij} B^2 \right)$$
In this tensor the diagonal elements are pressure, and the off diagonal elements are shear. So for $i\ne j$ and $E=0$ we get the portion of the Maxwell stress tensor which is only shear and only due to the magnetic field. That is $$\sigma_{ij} \bigg|_{i\ne j, E=0} = \frac{B_i B_j}{\mu_0} $$
As with any shear, this represents a momentum in the $i$ direction which is flowing across a surface normal to the $j$ direction. The only difference is that it is a little more difficult to conceptualize this momentum and its flow in a field, but that is a rather standard part of electromagnetism. If there is conductive or magnetizable material, then some of this momentum flow can be given to the matter causing measurable stress in the material.

In electric 3 phase induction motors we have a slip where $N_s,N$ are synchronous and actual lagging speed of rotor (RPM) respectively for any current to develop in the rotor. It is electromagnetic slightly different field speeds that can be also viewed as a constant shear between them:
$$ \frac{N_s-N}{N_s}\times 100,~\%.$$

I see you have tagged this "fusion" so I'm going to guess that you saw the term about a sheared-flow z-pinch device, likely Zap's?
If so, the shear is due to the movement of the plasma in the generated magnetic field. This causes it to flow at different speeds as one moves out from the central electrode. So it is a pretty standard definition of shear.
The theory is that this will suppress a number of classical instabilities that arise in pinching plasmas, in cylindrical arrangements mostly kink-related and any number of hydrodynamic modes. Whether or not that is true has yet to be demonstrated at scale.
